# How to zero elements of 3D Matrix with opencv Library?

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix

I'm struggling with zeroing elements of 3D matrix with opencv. 
I can zero all elements in 2D matrix like following way:

```
meta = new Mat(Mat::zeros(cluster,3,CV_32S));
```

I try to use the similar way to initialize elements with 0 in 3D matrix, it fails.

```
block = new Mat(Mat::zeros(3,dim,CV_32F));
```

Error message:

```
1>MatrixOp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class cv::MatExpr __cdecl cv::Mat::zeros(int,int const *,int)" (?zeros@Mat@cv@@SA?AVMatExpr@2@HPBHH@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall MatrixOp::MatrixOp(char *)" (??0MatrixOp@@QAE@PAD@Z)
```

I got one last way to initialize matrix. Traverse the matrix and set element value 0. But it seems labor-some.

```
for(int i=0;i<value_num;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<frame_no;j++)
        for(int k=0;k<cluster;k++)
            block->at<float>(i,j,k) = 0;
```

Can anyone throw me a better ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I remind you the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=size#mat-mat), you can use this constructor:

```
C++: Mat::Mat(int ndims, const int* sizes, int type, const Scalar& s)
```

passing cv::Scalar(0) should be good for your purposes.

```
int sizes[] = { 100, 100, 100 };
cv::Mat *matrix = new cv::Mat(3, sizes, CV_32FC1, cv::Scalar(0));
```

This should make a 3D matrix, a sort of cube with edge 100.

Comment: This is pretty cool. Scalar is super good tool. Appreciate your answer.

Comment: Yes they're really nice ;)