# openCV creating a 3D matrix with different sizes

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix

accroding to this 
http://answers.opencv.org/question/15917/how-to-access-data-from-a-cvmat/
 I have tried to create a 3D matrix

```
void AutomaticMacbethDetection::DrawMacbethROI(ColorCheckerBatchRGB ColorCheckerBatchRGB, int *** raw_frame,int _width, int _height,int colorOrder)
{  
    cv::Mat src;
    if (colorOrder == -1)
    {
        const int sizes[3]={_height,_width,3};
        src = cv::Mat::zeros(3, sizes, CV_32F);

    }else
    {
        const int sizes[3]={_height,_width,1};
        src = cv::Mat::zeros(3, sizes, CV_32F);
    }

    std::vector<float> channel;
    if (colorOrder == -1)
    {
        for (int w = 0; w < _width; w++)
        {               
            for (int h = 0; h < _height; h++)
            {
                float temp =raw_frame[h][w][0]; 
                channel.push_back(temp);
                src.at<float>(h,w,0) = temp;
                src.at<float>(h,w,1) = raw_frame[h][w][1];
                src.at<float>(h,w,2) = raw_frame[h][w][2];
            }               
        }   
    }
    else
    {
        for (int w = 0; w < _width; w++)
        {               
            for (int h = 0; h < _height; h++)
            {
                float temp =raw_frame[h][w][0]; 
                channel.push_back(temp);
                src.at<float>(h,w,0) = temp;
            }               
        }   
        float divider = Utilities::tprctile(channel,99.2);
        src = src/divider;
    }

    cv::imshow("test", src);
    cv::waitKey(0);
```

}

my function supports both RGB and Raw Image so I need to create a 100x100x1 matrix or a 100x100x3 matrix, depending on the image type.

however I get an exception in imshow()

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (p[-1] <= 2) in cv::Mat::MSize::operator (), file
 C:\buildslave64\win64_amdocl\2_4_PackSlave-win64-vc11-shared\opencv\modules\cor
e\include\opencv2/core/mat.hpp, line 712
```

can you please explain what is the problem?

Comment: See my answer to this question, the problem is similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19168573/how-to-zero-elements-of-3d-matrix-with-opencv-library/19168807#19168807

Comment: @Michele do I have to use cv::Mat* ?? I want to to use "/" division operator. and you can't do that for a pointer

Comment: no, it's not mandatory to use a pointer. You can always deference it with the * operator. You can also write `cv::Mat matrix(3, sizes, CV_32FC1, cv::Scalar(0));` and you don't have a pointer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I have found for this is using CV_32FC3 which means each cell of the matrix (x,y) has 3 values in it.
this is how you init the 3D matrix.

```
src = cv::Mat::zeros(_height,_width, CV_32FC3);
```

and now you have 3 cells which you need to access like so:

```
src.at<cv::Vec3f>(h,w)[0]
src.at<cv::Vec3f>(h,w)[1]
src.at<cv::Vec3f>(h,w)[2]
```

Please notice I'm using `Vec3f` and not `float` like i'm using in `CV_32F`

```
void AutomaticMacbethDetection::DrawMacbethROI(ColorCheckerBatchRGB ColorCheckerBatchRGB, int *** raw_frame,int _width, int _height,int colorOrder)
{

    cv::Mat src;
    std::vector<float> channel;
    if (colorOrder != -1 )
    {
        src = cv::Mat::zeros(_height,_width, CV_32F);
        for (int w = 0; w < _width; w++)
        {               
            for (int h = 0; h < _height; h++)
            {
                float temp =raw_frame[h][w][0]; 
                channel.push_back(temp);
                src.at<float>(h,w) = temp;
            }               
        }   
        float divider = Utilities::tprctile(channel,99.2);
        src = src/divider;

    }
    else
    {
        src = cv::Mat::zeros(_height,_width, CV_32FC3); 
        for (int w = 0; w < _width; w++)
        {               
            for (int h = 0; h < _height; h++)
            {
                float temp =raw_frame[h][w][0]; 
                channel.push_back(temp);
                src.at<cv::Vec3f>(h,w)[0] = raw_frame[h][w][0];
                src.at<cv::Vec3f>(h,w)[1] = raw_frame[h][w][1];
                src.at<cv::Vec3f>(h,w)[2] = raw_frame[h][w][2];
            }                       
        }
        float divider = Utilities::tprctile(channel,99.2);
        src = src/divider;
    }

    cv::resize(src,src,cv::Size(),0.3,0.3,cv::INTER_LINEAR);
    cv::imshow("detected", src);    
    cv::waitKey(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that you are trying to set a 3-layer zero mat in both cases:

```
const int sizes[3]={_height,_width,1};
src = cv::Mat::zeros(3, sizes, CV_32F);
```

C++: static MatExpr Mat::zeros(int ndims, const int* sz, int type) states that the first argument is the dimentions. This should here be 1 if you want a 1-layer mat.